# Is there any reason why multithreaded app will loop forever when win7 is screen locked?

Tags: c++, windows-7

I'm working on an application that uses multiple threads to process its data. The app is developped in C++ (Intel C++ comp. 9.1) and uses OpenMP. It is a 64 bit app running on Win7.

The problem is that when I run it during day, it runs correctly. But when I run it during night **after** the screen has been locked, it enters in a forever loop after a few processes.

To be more precise, the app is called many times for different files to process. The calls are done within a batch file (no problem there).

I found that it enters in the forever loop about 2 hours after the lock screen occurs.

I disabled all power saving settings. But nothing changed.

*It is not very clear as description but the reason is that I don't have a clue about the source of the problem. I just hope someone among you could have had the same problem (and found a fix!).* If you want more details, just let me know.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

---

As my tests go on, I installed the same setup (but in release rather than debug version) on another computer. I ran into the same problem after 20 minutes (after the screen lock) with another set of data. I ran the same data on my own computer (which is not locked) and everything was fine.

I'm **mystified**!

Comment: Attach the debugger to the process after it has hung and see where the issue is occurring.

Comment: That is what I did and that is how I saw that some threads where running forever. But these threads run correctly when I run the application and the computer is not *screen* locked...

Comment: So the threads run fine after it comes out of screen lock?

Comment: No, they continue to run in there forever loop.

Comment: Once you have it in the debugger, you need to step through the code until you come to the point where the infinite loop occurs and see what condition is (or isn't) being met - is it testing if a file exists? a window is visible? without investigating that you are just stumbling around in the dark.

Comment: What type of event causes your threads to exit? Do they wait wait on some resource? Do they just do some computational work then exit? Do they access data from disk files? network?

Comment: When the app loops forever, it seems to be in NTDLL.DLL. I can't debug this. To say the truth, the threads don't exit, they just loop forever. I know, it seems dark as the Dark Ages but I'll explore the case deeper this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you giving a thread priority that is taking control of the application?

Also, I would suggest taking running it through some kind of profiling, such as [VTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe/) as it can point out potential odd cases that could be causing an issue for you. (There is a free evaluation that you can try).

Comment: I have to say that the threading is _perfect_ when the app runs on the computer in normal state. The facts are that it enters in a forever loop (don't ask me why) **only when the computer is locked**. I will do more tests this morning and I will try to make it or to force it into this state to see what happens.

Comment: OK everyone, as I tough it is an algorithm error quite hard to track (my side, not MS side). It was a deadlock, the threads were waiting for a flag switch (done by the main thread) that was on its side waiting for a flag switch done by the process threads... Such problems occur...